Why Do Some Websites Not Accept Number Inputs from the Numeric Keypad?
Why do some websites do not accept number inputs from the number section on the right side of the keypad while 'Num Lock ON' (3x3 config on the right side that requires a 'Num Lock' key to activate)
Example: https://futureskillsprime.in/
I was trying to register on this website for a certification and apparently it does not accept input from the Num-pad.

Can you add some examples where that is the case?

Presumably because they rolled their own input field and listened only for certain key events. Very doubtful that it would be an intentional (UX) choice.

@LukeSawczak That was what I thought as well. Some examples would be nice to see if it’s true.

Related question: Keycodes for the Numeric Keypad

Site example added: https://learn.futureskillsprime.in/register. It was an OTP field and it only accepted numeric input from the main section

The safest way to know is to ask them. I can't think of any reason as well.

Bad implementation when trying to check you're entering a number.
I've seen this on a couple of website that are trying to restrict you so that you can only type numbers in a field (such as when entering a TOTP). They didthis by putting a JavaScript event on the field that detects the keycode of the key you press, and then ignores it if it's not a number. So they check if the keycode is between 48 for 0 and 57 for 9, and ignore all other codes.
However, they don't realise that keycodes are different from the key with a 0 on the top row of a keyboard (48) compared to the key with a 0 on a numpad (96) - so their JavaScript ends up unintentionally blocking the use of a the number because those keycodes are outside of the allowed range.
You can play around on a site like this to see the values returned by different keys.

Excellent answer. thank you!
